# Python: How to I better manage memory to prevent a `Killed 9` OOM error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, out-of-memory, geopy

I'd like to use memory more efficiently. My code is tripping an OOM memory error. When I run this, my virtual memory size increases significantly and I get a `Killed: 9` error.

The virtual memory goes up to 35GB: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qC2cy.png

My code takes an input of 130 business addresses and adds geo coordinates to each of them.

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
from geopy.exc import GeocoderTimedOut
from geopy.extra.rate_limiter import RateLimiter

# takes an input of addresses and adds coordinates
def addCoordinates(businessList):
    geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="myapp111", timeout=20)
    geocode = RateLimiter(
        geolocator.geocode,
        min_delay_seconds=3.0,
        error_wait_seconds=10.0,
        swallow_exceptions=False,
        max_retries=30,
    )

    i=1
    while i < len(businessList):
        longitude = ""
        latitude = ""
        geoLocation = ""
        geoAddress = ""
        entry = []

        # adds the city to each street address
        appendedLocation = (businessList[i][3] + ", San Francisco")
        geoLocation = geocode(appendedLocation)

        # when there is a match, add the address to the businessList
        if geoLocation is not None:
            geoAddress = geoLocation.address
            latitude = geoLocation.latitude
            longitude = geoLocation.longitude

            entry = [geoAddress, appendedLocation, str(latitude), str(longitude)]
            j=0
            while j < len(entry):
                businessList[i] += [entry[j]]
                j+=1    
        i+=1

    return businessList

# businessList has 130 businesses, with their name and category and address
businessList = [[0, '', 'Palomino', '345 Spear St', 'Mediterranean', 'Bars', 'American (New)'], [0, '', 'Barbara Pinseria & Cocktail Bar', '431 Columbus Ave', 'Cocktail Bars', 'Italian', 'Pizza'], [0, '1.', 'Executive Order Bar & Lounge', '868 Mission St', 'Coffee & Tea', 'Cocktail Bars', 'Lounges'], [0, '2.', 'Smuggler’s Cove', '650 Gough St', 'Venues & Event Spaces', 'Tiki Bars', 'Cocktail Bars'], [0, '3.', 'Alchemist Bar & Lounge', '679 3rd St', 'Lounges', 'Cocktail Bars', ''], [0, '4.', 'Holy Water', '309 Cortland Ave', 'Cocktail Bars', 'Beer Bar', ''], [0, '5.', 'Fireside Bar', '603 Irving St', 'Cocktail Bars', '', ''], [0, '6.', 'Benjamin Cooper', '398 Geary St', 'Cocktail Bars', 'Wine Bars', 'Beer Bar'], [0, '7.', 'Last Rites', '718 14th St', 'Cocktail Bars', 'Tiki Bars', ''], [0, '8.', 'The Pawn Shop', '993 Mission St', 'Speakeasies', 'Wine Bars', 'Tapas Bars'], [0, '9.', 'The View Lounge', '780 Mission St', 'Lounges', 'Beer, Wine & Spirits', ''], [0, '10.', 'Fool’s Errand', '639A Divisadero St', 'Wine Bars', 'Beer Bar', ''], [0, '11.', 'The Beehive', '842 Valencia St', 'Cocktail Bars', 'Lounges', ''], [0, '12.', 'Bar 821', '821 Divisadero St', 'Lounges', 'Cocktail Bars', ''], [0, '13.', 'Natives Bar', '5320 Geary Blvd', 'Bars', '', ''], [0, '14.', 'Last Call Bar', '3988 18th St', 'Gay Bars', 'Dive Bars', 'Pubs'], [0, '15.', 'Scarlet Lounge', '408 Clement St', 'Lounges', 'Cocktail Bars', ''], [0, '16.', 'Linden Room', '330 Gough St', 'Cocktail Bars', '', ''], [0, '17.', 'Rooftop 25', '25 Lusk St', 'Cocktail Bars', 'Tacos', 'American (Traditional)'], [0, '18.', 'The Black Horse London Pub', '1514 Union St', 'Pubs', '', ''], [0, '19.', 'Bourbon & Branch', '501 Jones St', 'Cocktail Bars', 'Venues & Event Spaces', 'Speakeasies'], [0, '20.', 'Tiki Haven', '1334 Noriega St', 'Tiki Bars', '', ''], [0, '21.', 'Pacific Cocktail Haven', '580 Sutter St', 'Cocktail Bars', '', ''], [0, '22.', 'Zam Zam', '1633 Haight St', 'Bars', '', ''], [0, '23.', 'Topsy’s Fun House', '260 Kearny St', 'Cocktail Bars', 'Lounges', ''], [0, '24.', 'The Office', '194 Church St', 'Venues & Event Spaces', 'Lounges', ''], [0, '25.', 'Local Edition', '691 Market St', 'Lounges', 'Cocktail Bars', 'Whiskey Bars'], [0, '26.', 'The Snug', '2301 Fillmore St', 'Cocktail Bars', 'American (Traditional)', 'Beer Bar'], [0, '27.', 'The Bitter End', '441 Clement St', 'Pubs', 'Dive Bars', ''], [0, '28.', 'Blackbird', '2124 Market St', 'Bars', 'Venues & Event Spaces', ''], [0, '29.', 'Seven Stills & Hard Frescos Taproom', '3645 Lawton St', 'Breweries', '', ''], [0, '30.', 'Novela', '662 Mission St', 'Cocktail Bars', 'Lounges', ''], [0, '', 'Laughing Monk Brewing', '1439 Egbert Ave', 'Beer Bar', 'Venues & Event Spaces', 'Breweries'], [1, '', 'Barbarossa Lounge', '714 Montgomery St', 'American (New)', 'Venues & Event Spaces', 'Cocktail Bars'], [1, '', 'The Office', '194 Church St', 'Lounges', 'Venues & Event Spaces', ''], [1, '31.', 'The Butterfly Lounge', 'add_manually', 'Cocktail Bars', 'Lounges', ''], [1, '32.', 'Last Stop Sports Bar and Lounge', '6192 Mission St', 'Sports Bars', 'Lounges', ''], [1, '33.', 'Bond Bar', '3079 16th St', 'Cocktail Bars', 'Lounges', ''], [1, '34.', 'Barbarossa Lounge', '714 Montgomery St', 'American (New)', 'Cocktail Bars', 'Venues & Event Spaces'], [1, '35.', 'Pagan Idol', '375 Bush St', 'Tiki Bars', 'Venues & Event Spaces', ''], [1, '36.', 'Coin-Op Game Room', '508 4th St', 'Bars', 'Eatertainment', 'American (Traditional)'], [1, '37.', 'Rickhouse', '246 Kearny St', 'Cocktail Bars', 'Venues & Event Spaces', 'Whiskey Bars'], [1, '38.', 'Speakeasy Ales & Lagers', '1195 Evans Ave', 'Breweries', 'Speakeasies', ''], [1, '39.', 'White Cap', '3608 Taraval St', 'Cocktail Bars', '', ''], [1, '40.', 'Rye', '688 Geary St', 'Lounges', '', ''], [1, '41.', 'Bar 587', '587 Post St', 'Lounges', 'Cocktail Bars', 'Sandwiches'], [1, '42.', 'After Hours', '3044 Taraval St', 'Sports Bars', 'Chicken Wings', ''], [1, '43.', 'The Social Study', '1795 Geary Blvd', 'Wine Bars', 'Cafes', ''], [1, '44.', 'The Alembic', '1725 Haight St', 'Bars', 'American (New)', 'Breakfast & Brunch'], [1, '45.', 'Broken Record', '1166 Geneva Ave', 'Dive Bars', '', ''], [1, '46.', 'Kava Lounge SF', '901 Divisadero St', 'Lounges', '', ''], [1, '47.', 'The Speakeasy SF', 'add_manually', 'Performing Arts', 'Speakeasies', ''], [1, '48.', 'Tunnel Top', '601 Bush St', 'Cocktail Bars', '', ''], [1, '49.', '83 Proof', '83 1st St', 'Whiskey Bars', 'Cocktail Bars', ''], [1, '50.', 'Trad’r Sam', '6150 Geary Blvd', 'Dive Bars', 'Pubs', 'Tiki Bars'], [1, '51.', 'Valley Tavern', '4054 24th St', 'Pubs', 'Sports Bars', ''], [1, '52.', 'Shotwell’s', '3349 20th St', 'Pubs', '', ''], [1, '53.', '24th Street Bar', '3336 24th St', 'Cocktail Bars', '', ''], [1, '54.', 'Horsefeather', '528 Divisidero St', 'Cocktail Bars', 'American (New)', ''], [1, '55.', 'Third Rail', '628 20th St', 'Cocktail Bars', '', ''], [1, '56.', 'Trick Dog', '3010 20th St', 'Cocktail Bars', 'American (New)', ''], [1, '57.', 'Hobson’s Choice', '1601 Haight St', 'Bars', '', ''], [1, '58.', 'The Blarney Stone', '5625 Geary Blvd', 'Pubs', 'Irish', ''], [1, '59.', 'Toronado', '547 Haight St', 'Dive Bars', 'Pubs', ''], [1, '60.', 'Ferment Drink Repeat - FDR Brewery', '2636 San Bruno Ave', 'Breweries', 'Beer Bar', ''], [1, '', 'Sakesan Sushi & Bistro', '626 Clement St', 'Sushi Bars', 'Karaoke', 'Japanese'], [2, '', 'Blackbird', '2124 Market St', 'Venues & Event Spaces', 'Bars', ''], [2, '', 'The Office', '194 Church St', 'Lounges', 'Venues & Event Spaces', ''], [2, '1.', 'Smuggler’s Cove', '650 Gough St', 'Venues & Event Spaces', 'Tiki Bars', 'Cocktail Bars'], [2, '2.', 'Last Rites', '718 14th St', 'Cocktail Bars', 'Tiki Bars', ''], [2, '3.', 'Holy Water', '309 Cortland Ave', 'Cocktail Bars', 'Beer Bar', ''], [2, '4.', 'Last Call Bar', '3988 18th St', 'Gay Bars', 'Dive Bars', 'Pubs'], [2, '5.', 'The Office', '194 Church St', 'Venues & Event Spaces', 'Lounges', ''], [2, '6.', 'Blackbird', '2124 Market St', 'Bars', 'Venues & Event Spaces', ''], [2, '7.', 'Woods Cervecería', '3801 18th St', 'Bars', 'Breweries', 'Venues & Event Spaces'], [2, '8.', 'The View Lounge', '780 Mission St', 'Lounges', 'Beer, Wine & Spirits', ''], [2, '9.', 'Brewcade', '2200 Market St', 'Bars', 'Arcades', ''], [2, '10.', 'Third Rail', '628 20th St', 'Cocktail Bars', '', ''], [2, '11.', 'Mr Tipple’s Recording Studio', '39 Fell St', 'Cocktail Bars', 'Jazz & Blues', 'Music Venues'], [2, '12.', 'Local Edition', '691 Market St', 'Lounges', 'Cocktail Bars', 'Whiskey Bars'], [2, '13.', 'Fermentation Lab', '1230 Market St', 'Gastropubs', 'Beer Bar', ''], [2, '14.', 'The Beer Hall', '1 Polk St', 'Beer Bar', '', ''], [2, '15.', 'Churchill', '198 Church St', 'Lounges', '', ''], [2, '16.', 'Novela', '662 Mission St', 'Cocktail Bars', 'Lounges', ''], [2, '17.', 'Emporium SF', '616 Divisadero St', 'Bars', 'Venues & Event Spaces', 'Arcades'], [2, '18.', 'Topsy’s Fun House', '260 Kearny St', 'Cocktail Bars', 'Lounges', ''], [2, '19.', 'Lucky 13', '2140 Market St', 'Dive Bars', '', ''], [2, '20.', '83 Proof', '83 1st St', 'Whiskey Bars', 'Cocktail Bars', ''], [2, '21.', 'Speakeasy Ales & Lagers', '1195 Evans Ave', 'Breweries', 'Speakeasies', ''], [2, '22.', 'The Sea Star', '2289 3rd St', 'Dive Bars', 'Cocktail Bars', 'Pool Halls'], [2, '23.', 'The Social Study', '1795 Geary Blvd', 'Wine Bars', 'Cafes', ''], [2, '24.', 'Virgil’s Sea Room', '3152 Mission St', 'Cocktail Bars', '', ''], [2, '25.', 'The Hot Spot', '1414 Market St', 'Dive Bars', '', ''], [2, '26.', 'Rickhouse', '246 Kearny St', 'Cocktail Bars', 'Venues & Event Spaces', 'Whiskey Bars'], [2, '27.', 'Tunnel Top', '601 Bush St', 'Cocktail Bars', '', ''], [2, '28.', 'School Night', '601 19th St', 'Latin American', 'Lounges', 'Cocktail Bars'], [2, '29.', 'Pagan Idol', '375 Bush St', 'Tiki Bars', 'Venues & Event Spaces', ''], [2, '30.', 'Horsefeather', '528 Divisidero St', 'Cocktail Bars', 'American (New)', ''], [2, '', 'Palomino', '345 Spear St', 'Mediterranean', 'American (New)', 'Bars'], [3, '', 'Blackbird', '2124 Market St', 'Venues & Event Spaces', 'Bars', ''], [3, '', 'The Office', '194 Church St', 'Lounges', 'Venues & Event Spaces', ''], [3, '31.', 'Triple Voodoo Brewery & Tap Room', '2245 3rd St', 'Breweries', 'Venues & Event Spaces', ''], [3, '32.', 'Old Devil Moon', '3472 Mission St', 'Cocktail Bars', 'American (Traditional)', ''], [3, '33.', 'Iron Horse Cocktails', '25 Maiden Ln', 'Cocktail Bars', 'Lounges', ''], [3, '34.', 'El Rio', '3158 Mission St', 'Music Venues', 'Dive Bars', ''], [3, '35.', 'Barebottle Brewing Company', '1525 Cortland Ave', 'Breweries', 'Venues & Event Spaces', ''], [3, '36.', 'The Treasury', '200 Bush St', 'Cocktail Bars', 'American (Traditional)', ''], [3, '37.', 'Dogpatch Saloon', '2496 3rd St', 'Sports Bars', '', ''], [3, '38.', 'Ferment Drink Repeat - FDR Brewery', '2636 San Bruno Ave', 'Breweries', 'Beer Bar', ''], [3, '39.', '3rd Street Tap Room', '251 3rd St', 'Bars', 'Brewpubs', ''], [3, '40.', 'Broken Record', '1166 Geneva Ave', 'Dive Bars', '', ''], [3, '41.', 'Barbarossa Lounge', '714 Montgomery St', 'American (New)', 'Cocktail Bars', 'Venues & Event Spaces'], [3, '42.', 'Wild Side West', '424 Cortland Ave', 'Gay Bars', 'Dive Bars', ''], [3, '43.', 'The Cordial', '163 Jessie St', 'Bars', '', ''], [3, '44.', 'Cafe Du Nord', '2174 Market St', 'Venues & Event Spaces', 'Bars', 'Music Venues'], [3, '45.', 'Hawthorn', '46 Geary St', 'Cocktail Bars', 'Lounges', 'Venues & Event Spaces'], [3, '46.', 'The Lark Bar', '29 3rd St', 'Sports Bars', 'Beer Bar', 'Cocktail Bars'], [3, '47.', 'The Mix', '4086 18th St', 'Gay Bars', '', ''], [3, '48.', 'Fly Bar', '762 Divisadero St', 'Bars', 'American (Traditional)', ''], [3, '49.', 'The Lucky Horseshoe', '453 Cortland Ave', 'Dive Bars', 'Music Venues', 'Sports Bars'], [3, '50.', 'Magnolia Dogpatch', '2505 3rd St', 'American (New)', 'Brewpubs', 'Bars'], [3, '51.', 'Rocks Den', '4431 Mission St', 'Lounges', 'Sports Bars', ''], [3, '52.', 'Swirl on Castro', '572 Castro St', 'Beer, Wine & Spirits', 'Wine Bars', ''], [3, '53.', 'Buddha Lounge', '901 Grant Ave', 'Dive Bars', '', ''], [3, '54.', 'Blush!', '476 Castro St', 'Wine Bars', 'French', ''], [3, '55.', 'Beaux', '2344 Market St', 'Gay Bars', 'Dance Clubs', 'Cocktail Bars'], [3, '56.', 'Cafe Terminus', '16 California St', 'Cocktail Bars', 'Coffee & Tea', ''], [3, '57.', 'Hazel Southern Bar & Kitchen', '1446 Market St', 'Southern', 'Whiskey Bars', 'American (New)'], [3, '58.', 'Li Po Cocktail Lounge', '916 Grant Ave', 'Dive Bars', 'Cocktail Bars', ''], [3, '59.', 'Natoma Cabana', '90 Natoma St', 'Cocktail Bars', '', ''], [3, '60.', 'Rock Bar', '80 29th St', 'Bars', '', ''], [3, '', 'Beaux', '2344 Market St', 'Gay Bars', 'Dance Clubs', 'Cocktail Bars']]

businessList = addCoordinates(businessList)
```

I tried to find out what was using memory with             `sys.getsizeof()`, but the businessList object remains relatively small (1272) and each entry is also small (96).

Is there a glaring error for how I'm managing memory?

Comment: `getsizeof` doesn't help with the size of lists.  Lists contain pointer to other objects including other lists.  In effect it doesn't tell us any more than `len()`.

Comment: You can get an approximation of the blameable size usage from `def total_size(obj): return sys.getsizeof(obj) + sum([total_size(o)/(sys.getrefcount(o) - NUM_LOCAL_REFS) for o in gc.get_referents(obj)])` but this won't handle recursive structures, and might not handle all C-allocated memory. Normally, reasoning about your code is more useful.

Comment: You have a memory leak. I can't see where. Log the len of your lists as the program progresses. If that does not help you can try to use a memory profiler. I have used [objgraph](https://mg.pov.lt/objgraph/). [This one](https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/) seems friendlier.